# classNotFound Exception when using JDBC for MYSQL on Tomcat in eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, classnotfoundexception

This seems to be a common problem, but I could not find a working solution.  I've looked through dozens of thread and have been working with my teacher.
I am trying to connect to MYSQL using JDBC.  I'm also using a tomcat server and running xubuntu 12.04.  I am getting ClassNotFound exception.

I've tried the JDBC mysql-connector-java.jar driver placed in both /tomact/lib and /usr/share/java  and have manually built paths in each instance.   I've also tried adding paths through deploy assembly.  I've tried using EXPORT CLASSPATH.  Nothing has worked.  I cannot get this exception to stop being thrown.  Does anyone have other solutions I can try?

my code:

```
public static Connection getConnection() {
    if(connection!=null){
        return connection;
    }else{
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://144.91.20.136:3306/jewelryInventoryGallison";
            String username = "javaee";
            String password = "mills2012";

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, username, password);
            return connection;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

test class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{ 
      Connection conn = DatabaseUtils.getConnection();
      Statement st = conn.createStatement();
      ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Inventory");
      while(rs.next()) {
       System.out.println(rs.getString("name"));
      }

 }
```

and trace:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
at utils.DatabaseUtils.getConnection(DatabaseUtils.java:19)
at utils.DatabaseUtils.main(DatabaseUtils.java:34)
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at utils.DatabaseUtils.main(DatabaseUtils.java:35)

your help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: May be you are missing drivers ...!
This may be help you
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Comment: thanks Chella,  but I have the drivers.  I'm sorry my post wasn't clear.  that was what I meant by JDBC jar

Comment: @user1857898 either accept any answer or let us know more about your problem else you will get close vote

Comment: I'm sorry coder, I was away from my computer.  I also didn't see your post when I refreshed the page.  I do have the library you are referring to.  I put down all I know.  I'm sorry I wasn't more explicit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventhough connector is configured in classpath tomcat doesn't load that correctly. so paste the mysql-connector-jar file in lib folder under WEB_INF also and try running again.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

You missing `MySQL` driver library. Since, you are using `Mysql` database, make sure you have included [`mysql-connector-java`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.8-dmr</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Coders,  I'm sorry it took me so long to get back to you.  I was AFK.  I do have that library to which you referred.  I'm sorry, I didn't call it by its full name in original post.  I have researched a lot of thread that had me move that library to different locations, build paths to it in several ways.  nothing worked.  So I am looking for an alternative solution

Comment: @user1857898 did add the library, which i have mentioned in my post. What is the problem now ?? You are getting same error or different??

Answer (score 2):

Putting the MySQL-connector-java-5.1.6.jar in the Tomcat/lib directory finally worked for me.  Shouldn't have to do this so I suspect my Tomcat installation isn't optimum and deploying the war file might be problematic

Answer (score 1):

Version Mismatch could cause this error. I myself was stuck in this error for days. Please check the version of jdbc connector. Latest connectors require java 1.8. In my case my tomcat version didn't support the connector version i added so please check for that also.

PS : Tomcat - 8.0.32 ; mysql-connector - 5.1.30 with java 1.7 works (Y)

Answer (score 0):

modify 'common.loader' property in the 'catalina.properties' file in the tomcat 'conf' folder as shown below

```
common.loader=${catalina.base}/lib,${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar,${catalina.home}/lib,${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar
```

Also add 'mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar' in the tomcat 'lib' folder

Comment: @user1857898 - after doing above, you must restart tomcat

Comment: @user1857898 - you already added mysql connector jar files to eclipse right?